# c++ how to create iterator over one field of a struct vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, iteration

I have a structure of all primitive types, like so:

```
struct record {
    int field1;
    double field2;
}
```

I have a vector of instances of this struct, like so:

```
vector<record> records;
```

Is it possible/what is the best way to create a `vector<int>::iterator` that will iterate over `field1`?
What about if I used an array `record records[n]`? I need something that looks like `vector<int>::iterator`.

EDIT: I need something that IS a `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong way. Create an iterator over the container and only access field1 if that is all you want

Comment: @B-Brock are you trying to search with this vector, or what?

Comment: Why do you need such an iterator?  Are you passing it to another function?  If yes, what are the requirements of that function (pointer, random-access iterator, vector iterator, ?)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes--exactly. The function I want to pass it to takes a `begin` and `end` iterator of type `vector<int>::iterator`. I already use it in other parts of my code, passing in iterators from actual `vector<int>`s.

Comment: It's always the same "type" of data--for me the `int` represents clock jumps, so I was thinking of doing an inheritance thing, but I don't really want to make a struct of 1 field, you know?

Comment: @B-Brock: Inheritance wouldn't help... Just because `class X` derives from `struct Y` doesn't mean there is any connection between `std::vector<X>` and `std::vector<Y>`.

Comment: I would have `struct Y` and `struct Z` inherit from `struct X`--`Z` would be my record struct and Y would be a struct containing just `field1`.

Comment: @B-Brock: And there would be no relation between `std::vector<X>`, `std::vector<Y>`, and `std::vector<Z>`.  No substitutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're out of luck.

`vector<int>::iterator` is not polymorphic<sup>1</sup>.  There's no place to reach in and change the pointer step size.  `vector<int>::iterator` iterates a sequence of **contiguous** `int` objects, only, and your `int` objects are not stored contiguously.

This is why all the C++ standard algorithms are templated to accept iterators of any type.  If you make your function a template accepting arbitrary iterator types, you can use an iterator adaptor like the one Snps wrote.

---

<sup>1</sup>Polymorphism is *slow* relative to pointer arithmetic, no one would use `std::vector` if it didn't have similar performance to a plain array

Answer (score 5):

### Making an iterator adaptor

First of all, the simplest solution is to iterate over the container and access the fields from the iterator.

```
for (auto&& r : records) {
    int value = r.field1;
    /* do something with 'value' */
}
```

Anyway, if you *really* want an iterator that returns `field1` when dereferenced you can easily implement an iterator adaptor that derives from the container's own iterator.

```
struct my_it : public std::vector<record>::iterator {
    using std::vector<record>::iterator::iterator;
    int operator*() { return std::vector<record>::iterator::operator*().field1; }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
for (my_it it = std::begin(records); it != std::end(records); ++it) {
    int value = *it; // Dereferencing now returns 'field1'.
}
```

### Is it an XY problem?

As explained in the answer by [Ben Voigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27307769/873025), there is no way to create a `std::vector<int>::iterator` that iterates over something else than `int` elements stored in a contiguous array.

If you need a function that takes input iterators then make it a *template function*. This way it will work with iterators for *any* container type. This is how all the algorithms in the standard library is implemented.

```
template <typename InputIt>
void func(InputIt first, InputIt last) {
    for (; first != last; ++first) {
        value = *it; // Dereferences input iterator of any type.
    }
}
```

Iterators should be interfaced through their operations (i.e. read, increment, decrement, random access), *not* their explicit type. Iterators are categorized by the number of operations they support.

For instance, if you need to iterate over a range and read all the values in a single pass then you want **input iterators** as arguments. The type of the iterator itself should be irrelevant.

[See this for more info about iterator categories](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion! I need it to "look like" a `vector<int>::iterator` though.

Comment: I made an edit--I should have said BE a `vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: This is helpful but I think  
`
using std::vector<record>::iterator::iterator;
`
is syntactically incorrect. iterator doesn't define ::iterator.

Also, I had to define a constructor for struct my_it from std::vector<record>::iterator for this to work. Otherwise I couldn't create my_it from std::begin(records). Something like
`my_it(std::vector<record>::iterator it) { *(std::vector<record>::iterator*)this = it; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can use lambdas on your original `vector`.

For example:

```
for_each(records.begin(), records.end(), [](record& foo){/*operate on foo.field1 here*/});
```

Note that the vast majority of other algorithms also accept lambdas, so you can just iterate over your original `vector` using the lambda to access just `field1`.

I'm being presumptuous here but the behavior you are looking for seems to closely resemble that of a `map` so you might wanna have a look at that.

I suppose that you're into Boost and evil you could also cobble something together with this: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are asking for something like this

```
for(std::vector<record>::iterator i=records.begin(), end=records.end(); i!=end; ++i)
{
    std::cout << i->field1 << std::endl;
}
```

Or in C++11

```
for(auto i=records.begin(), end=records.end(); i!=end; ++i)
{
    std::cout << i->field1 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a member iterator, you can do something like this:

```c++
template <class M>
struct member_traits;

template <class T, class C>
struct member_traits<T C::*>
{
    using class_type = C;
    using return_type = T;
};

template <class Iterator, class C, class M>
struct member_iterator : Iterator
{
public:
    using Iterator::Iterator;

    template <class I, class Member>
    member_iterator(I&& begin, Member&& member)
        : std::vector<C>::iterator(std::forward<I>(begin))
        , member(std::forward<Member>(member))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_member_pointer<Member>::value,
                      "Member must be dereferenceable");
    }

    typename member_traits<M>::return_type& operator*()
    {
        return (*static_cast<Iterator&>(*this)).*member;
    }
private:
    M member;
};

template <class Member, class Iterator>
auto make_member_iterator(Member&& member, Iterator&& it)
    -> member_iterator<std::decay_t<Iterator>, typename member_traits<Member>::class_type, std::decay_t<Member>>
{
    return {std::forward<Iterator>(it), std::forward<Member>(member)};
}

struct Record
{
    int field1;
    double field2;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Record> v { {1, 1.0}, {2, 2.0}, {3, 3.0} };

    for (auto it = make_member_iterator(&Record::field1, v.begin()); it != v.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75b17dd0b67b48e7)</kbd>

Comment: Wouldn't it be more conventional to use base-call syntax, like `return Iterator::operator*().*member;`?  Or is your concern that `operator*` might be a non-member?