# Taking part of std::vector C++

Tags: c++, struct, stdvector

In my code I have something like this:

```
struct SomeStruct
{
  int test1;
  int test2;
  float test3;
  float test4;
};
std::vector<SomeStruct> SomeStructs;
```

I am looking for a way to get a part of that vector in a continues manner, So that I can access it with a pointer or a c-array.

Suppose I want a pointer to access only the part of the struct that are test2.
I want to pass that part of the vector to a C API, Is it possible?

I'm trying to avoid creating a new std::vector/c-array.

How It look's like in memory(kind of):

[image]

Comment: There is no language "C/C++", vector is a purely C++ construct so please remove C from title and tags. Can you give more information on what you mean by: I want a pointer to access only that column. Can you specify what the pointer is for? To grant access to some user, to pass into a C API...

Comment: "I am looking for a way to get a part of that vector in a continues manner, So that I can access it with a pointer or a c-array." sorry, that's impossible; a `vector<SomeStruct>` is laid out in memory as a sequence of adjacent `SomeStruct` instances, so each element of your `test2` column is `sizeof(SomeStruct)` bytes apart, instead of being just `sizeof(int)` bytes apart as it would be in a `int[]`. So, unless you copy that data out, you cannot have a pointer to "just that column" and use it as if it was a pointer to an element in a regular array of `int`s.

Comment: Change your C++ code to use struct of arrays (SoA) instead of array of structs (AoS). That is, one vector per column. Wrap it in a class with overloaded operators for convenient C++ API. Pass `std::vector::data()` to C API.

Comment: @Drop I'll try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, what you are asking for is impossible. Quick review:

1. We can clearly see that the test2 entries of the struct are not currently laid out contiguously in memory, because they are just one member of a struct that is contiguous, so clearly the other struct elements sit in between each occurence of test2.
2. You want them to be contiguous, so you need a different memory layout than you currently have.
3. You don't want to create a new vector or array, so you are stuck with your current memory layout, which is wrong.

Your options are like so:

1. Change the variable to be say 4 vectors of variables instead of one vector of structs.
2. Create a new vector when you need one.
3. Don't use a C API that requires contiguous memory.

For 3 it is worth noting that some C APIs, notably BLAS, supported "strided" arrays which means that there is a fixed size gap between elements, which would solve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

To implement this in an idiomatic manner you will need to roll your own custom `iterator` that returns that field specifically.

Take a look at [c++ how to create iterator over one field of a struct vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307373/c-how-to-create-iterator-over-one-field-of-a-struct-vector)

C and C++ interoperability is a vastly different problem. To simplify things you may just want to implement it in C.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to access just the contents of each `test2` from a pointer or array, because the `test2` members are not contiguous in memory even if the structs in the vector are. There's other data in the struct, so you need to skip over that to read each `test2`.

When you find yourself asking a question like this, try thinking about other data structures you can use that would make the problem easier to solve. For this case, perhaps a `std::unordered_map` would be a good choice.

```
std::unordered_map<int,SomeStruct> map;
// make a struct...
map.insert(std::make_pair<int,SomeStruct>(a_struct.test2,a_struct));
// add a bunch more structs...
// get an iterator to all the keys in the map (ie. something like a pointer to all test2 members)
key_iterator = map.begin()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you well, i think its possible.

```
struct SomeStruct
    {
        int test1;
        int test2;
        float test3;
        float test4;
    };

   int size = 3;// whatever size

   vector<SomeStruct> myStruct(size);
    myStruct[0].test1 = 0;
    myStruct[1].test1 = 1;
    myStruct[2].test1 = 2;

    /* myPtest1 will allow you to get the test1 part of myStruct in a 
    contiguous memory manner*/ 

    int *myPtest1 = new int(myStruct.size());

    for(int i = 0; i< myStruct.size(); i++)
        myPtest1[i] = myStruct[i].test1;

    // for illustration.
    cout << myPtest1[0] << endl; // 0
    cout << myPtest1[1] << endl; // 1
    cout << myPtest1[2] << endl; // 2
```

You can now pass `myPointer` to your API, myPointer gives you access to only `test1` part of `myStruct` vector.
you can do same for the rest of the `SomeStruct` attributes.

Comment: @JohnMiz If i got you well, i think its possible

Answer (score -1):

If you want to access it in a for loop you can do:

```
for (const auto& iterator: SomeStructs)
{
    const int& test2 = iterator.test2;
    // do what you need to do
}
```

If you need the j-th element:

```
const int& test2 = SomeStructs[j].test2
```

In this way you are not making extra copies but you are directly referencing items from vector. Remove const if you need to change the value